# What is the derivative of the ReLu of a Matrix with respect to a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I want to compute $\frac{\partial r(ZZ^tY)}{\partial Z}$ where the ReLu function is a nonlinear operator $r(x)=max(0,x)$ and $Z \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is a matrix.

I am wondering also if the derivative of the transpose is the transpose of the derivative of my expression, i.e., $\frac{\partial r(ZZ^tY)^t}{\partial Z}=\big(\frac{\partial r(ZZ^tY)}{\partial Z}\big)^t.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hadn't previously heard of the [ReLu function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_%28neural_networks%29), but based on the description, its derivative is the  [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function),
$$
  \frac{dr(x)}{dx} = H(x)
$$
Since your argument is a matrix of unspecified shape (square? rectangular?) and since there is no partial ordering for matrices in general, I assume that you are applying the function in an element-wise fashion.

When applied element-wise to a matrix argument ($X=ZZ^TY$), the differential of the function can be expressed using the Hadamard product ($\circ$) as 
$$\eqalign{
 dr &= H \circ dX \cr
    &= H \circ (dZ\,Z^TY + Z\,dZ^TY) \cr
}$$
Since $\big(\frac{\partial r}{\partial Z}\big)$ is a matrix-by-matrix derivative (aka $4^{th}$-order tensor) your question about taking its transpose is not clear. Instead
$$
\frac{\partial r(ZZ^TY)^T}{\partial Z} = \frac{\partial r(Y^TZZ^T)}{\partial Z}
$$
assuming, once again, that you are applying the function element-wise.